# Find the number of cosets$ [G:H] $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Assume that $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$, that $G =\ <a> $, that $k|n$ , and that $H=<a^k>$.

Find $[G:H] $ the number of cosets to the subgroup H

I think that since $k|n$ $\Rightarrow$ $<a^k> = e$

then $[G:H] = 0 $

Am I right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't ever be possible that $[G : H] = 0$, since there's always at least one coset (namely $H$ itself).

Alternatively, note that by Lagrange's Theorem,

$$[G : H] = \frac{|G|}{|H|} = \frac{|a|}{|a^k|}$$

This certainly can't ever be $0$.

---

It's also not correct that $\langle a^k \rangle = \{e\}$; if we had $n | k$, this would be true.

---

For the correct result, note that

$$\left(a^k\right)^{n/k} = e$$

so that $|a^k| \le \frac{n}{k}$. Next, it's not too hard to show that $|a^k| = \frac{n}{k}$, since if we had

$$(a^k)^m = e$$

with $m < \frac{n}{k}$, then $|a| \le km < n = |a|$, a contradiction. Hence,

$$[G : H] = \frac{n}{n/k} = k$$

Comment: I thought that it is good to avoid this kind of formula of Lagrange's Theorem just because we might have a zero number of cosets

Comment: @Logarithm There can't ever be no cosets, since $H = eH = He$ will always be both a left and right coset.

Comment: T.Bongers : that seems right but I remember the professor said that it is good to avoid that division format for some reason and I think that was because we might end up with zero cosets

Comment: @Logarithm If the groups are infinite, then the division isn't necessarily defined. That *is* a concern, but it's not an issue here.

Comment: @Logarithm Not quite. You can't divide through the bars like that - the order - see my updated answer for the correct solution.

Comment: @ T.Bongers : I have to delete my answer.

Comment: @ T.Bongers: Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate it. You review saved me some terrific future mistakes

Comment: @Logarithm Glad I could help :)